# IntelliJ IDEA Test FTP Connecton to '127.0.0.1' invalid descendent file name "/"

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, goland

"Mac OS transmit" can access normally, but reports this when you arrive at the IntelliJ IDEA

[image]

Comment: You may have a file named `/` or file name starts with `/`. Double check that and rename/delete such file (or folder). https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-deployment.html#ftp-issue-invalid-descendent-file-name

Comment: As a workaround, you can try making PhpStorm use LIST instead of MLSD in the advanced FTP options.